# SQL: Find the value corresponding to the minimum date of a group and add it to the table in the query

Tags: sql

I have the below table:

The dates will run until Jan of next year for both periods and it has more countries, cat1, 2, 3. This is just showing a few combinations

| yyyymmdd | period | country | cat1 | cat2 | cat3 | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20191201 | A | US | Sports | Cycle | long | 33 |
| 20191201 | A | US | Sports | Cycle | Short | 35 |
| 20191201 | A | US | Sports | Running | long | 28 |
| 20191201 | A | US | Sports | Running | short | 29 |
| 20191201 | A | US | Arts |  |  |  |
| 20191202 | A | US | Sports | Cycle | long | 43 |
| 20191202 | A | US | Sports | Cycle | Short | 44 |
| 20191202 | A | US | Sports | Running | long | 35 |
| 20191202 | A | US | Sports | Running | short | 37 |
| 20191202 | A | US | Arts |  |  |  |
| 20201201 | B | US | Sports | Cycle | long | 33 |
| 20201201 | B | US | Sports | Cycle | Short | 35 |
| 20201201 | B | US | Sports | Running | long | 28 |
| 20201201 | B | US | Sports | Running | short | 29 |
| 20201201 | B | US | Arts |  |  |  |

I like to find the score from day 1  for each groupings (period, country, cat1, cat2, cat3) and add this day 1 score as a additional column so it looks like this:

| yyyymmdd | period | country | cat1 | cat2 | cat3 | score | score_day1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20191201 | A | US | Sports | Cycle | long | 33 | 33 |
| 20191201 | A | US | Sports | Cycle | Short | 35 | 35 |
| 20191201 | A | US | Sports | Running | long | 28 | 28 |
| 20191201 | A | US | Sports | Running | short | 29 | 29 |
| 20191201 | A | US | Arts |  |  |  |  |
| 20191202 | A | US | Sports | Cycle | long | 43 | 33 |
| 20191202 | A | US | Sports | Cycle | Short | 44 | 35 |
| 20191202 | A | US | Sports | Running | long | 35 | 28 |
| 20191202 | A | US | Sports | Running | short | 37 | 29 |
| 20191202 | A | US | Arts |  |  |  |  |
| 20201201 | B | US | Sports | Cycle | long | 41 | 41 |
| 20201201 | B | US | Sports | Cycle | Short | 38 | 38 |
| 20201201 | B | US | Sports | Running | long | 50 | 50 |
| 20201201 | B | US | Sports | Running | short | 51 | 51 |
| 20201201 | B | US | Arts |  |  |  |  |
| 20201202 | B | US | Sports | Cycle | long | 44 | 41 |
| 20201202 | B | US | Sports | Cycle | Short | 51 | 38 |
| 20201202 | B | US | Sports | Running | long | 60 | 50 |
| 20201202 | B | US | Sports | Running | short | 38 | 51 |
| 20201202 | B | US | Arts |  |  |  |  |

Will appreciate any help. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `left join` but get the latest score first using `rownum()`

```
select b.*, a.score
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by period, country, cat1, cat2, cat3
        order by yyyymmmdd asc) as rn from test) a
left join test b
     on b.period = a.period and b.country=a.country and a.cat1 = b.cat1
            and a.cat2 = b.cat2 and a.cat3 = b.cat3 and a.rn=1
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=rrafp0Vshm)

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer?

SELECT yyyymmdd, period, country, cat1, cat2, cat3, score,
(select score from tbl t2 where yyyymmdd=(select min(yyyymmdd) from tbl where period=t1.period) and t1.period=t2.period and t1.country=t2.country and t1.cat1=t2.cat1 and t1.cat2=t2.cat2 and t1.cat3=t2.cat3 limit 1) score_day1 from tbl t1

Here is a fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/njLJnbNkFEdjSNUfopX7Ye/0

Comment: thanks for helping. but why tbl t2 where yyyymmdd is = 20191201? 
tbl t2 has date running from 20191201 to 20201201.

Comment: Sorr. I misunderstood. I thought you wanted the beginning of the year. I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try using `subquery` and `JOIN`.

**Query:**

```
SELECT t.yyyymmdd, t.period, t.country, t.cat1, t.cat2, t.cat3, t.score, 
       sq.score AS score_day1 
FROM t
LEFT JOIN
          (
           SELECT yyyymmdd, period, country, cat1, cat2, cat3, score 
           FROM 
               (
                SELECT yyyymmdd, period, country, cat1, cat2, cat3, score, 
                       RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY period ORDER BY yyyymmdd ASC) AS rnk
                FROM t
               ) AS r
           WHERE rnk=1
          ) AS sq
     ON t.period=sq.period 
     AND t.country=sq.country 
     AND t.cat1=sq.cat1
     AND t.cat2=sq.cat2
     AND t.cat3=sq.cat3
ORDER BY t.period, t.yyyymmdd
```

**Explanation:**

- Rank is used to find out first date for each `period`
- Then taking the scores and other info with rank as `1`
- Then joining back to `original` table

See demo in *[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=202d3de19ad9120d76e67c80421aa09e)*